# Bootstrapvalidator validating fields without being told so

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, validation

Basically, I'm running bootstrapvalidator on a form, and it seems to be deciding what to validate (and how) on its own. While I know this isnt technically what its doing, it really does feel like it.

My form:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="regcv" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstname" class="control-label">First name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastname" class="control-label">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="verifyemail" class="control-label">Verify email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="verifyemail" name="verifyemail" placeholder="Email verification">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone" class="control-label">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="+47 00 00 00 00">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="freetext" class="control-label">Free text (<small>optional</small>)</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="freetext" rows="16" name="freetext" placeholder="Anything you feel would be applicable, a full resume or similar"></textare
a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cv">Upload CV</label>
    <input type="file" id="cv" name="cv[]" accept="application/pdf">
    <p class="help-block">Accepted fileformats: .pdf.</p>
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="certs">Upload certificates</label>
    <input type="file" id="certs" name="certs[]" accept="application/pdf">
    <p class="help-block">Accepted fileformats: .pdf.</p>
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
```

When the form looks like above, it validates the first four fields (firstname, lastname, email and verifyemail) correctly, but disables the submit button without marking anything as invalid. However, if I change the 'phone' field to type='email', I can force my way through by hitting 'Submit', whereas the field gets validated, and I can click 'Submit' again and actually send the data. It also alters the form and adds data-bv-field='phone' for some strange reason.

My JS:

```
    $('#regcv').bootstrapValidator({
fields: {
firstname: {
validators: {
notEmpty: {
message: 'Required field'
}
}
},
lastname: {
validators: {
notEmpty: {
message: 'Required field'
}
}
},
email: {
validators: {
notEmpty: {
message: 'Required field'
},
emailAddress: {
message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
              }
}
},
verifyemail: {
validators: {
notEmpty: {
message: 'Required field'
          },
identical: {
field: 'email',
       message: 'Email does not match'
           }
            }
             },
             },
feedbackIcons: {
valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
       invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
       validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
               },
        submitHandler: function (validator, form, submitButton) {
                var form = new FormData($('#regcv')[0]);
                $.ajax({
url: 'ajax/action.php',
type: 'POST',
xhr: function () {
var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
if (myXhr.upload) {
myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progress, false);
}
return myXhr;
},
success: function (res) {
$('#content_here_please').html(res);
},
error: function (request, error) {
alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
},
data: form,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false
});
//$("#regcv :input").attr('disabled', true);
}
});
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nz7ej/

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Forgot to mention, but removing the field itself (the phone field) doesnt help, the form still wont validate, even if zero references to the field exists, and all current fields are valid.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the validation to work by changing the phone input field type back to "text" and adding a phone validator in the JS list of validators:

```
            phone: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Required'
                    },
                    phone: {
                        country: 'US',
                        message: 'Enter a valid phone number'
                    }
                }
            },
```

Based on your placeholder text, it looks like you want to validate non-US numbers. Refer to this chart to see what country code to pass to the phone validator:

https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search

Though it looks like current bootstrapvalidattor only works for US and UK phone numbers out of the box:

http://bootstrapvalidator.com/validators/phone/

Finally, note the TidyUp button on JSFiddle toolbar -- it makes your code much more readable.